# Determine the path to a video file

Tags: ios, swift

Okay what should be a simple step is resulting in null results?  This Swift code results in "no good" everytime.  The mp4 is in the assets.xcassets folder in the project.  I have tried multiple different mp4s that are there, and still comes up with same result.  I know I am missing something simple?

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Pow", ofType: "mp4") {
    print("all good")
} else {
    print("no good")
}
```

Comment: this address for root file project and if you want to use this address you must move your file to root folder else you must set assert.xcassets address to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, something simple.  Move Pow.mp4 out of assets and place it with your other swift files.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the mp4 file is in the root directory or inside Assets.xcassets it should work , you have to open the assests and drag the mp4 file to it below app icons

[image]

make sure target is checked 
 [image]

then here is the log of the file path 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, that did it.  Moving it outside the assets and ensuring that it is a 'target' made it happen.  Thankyou!

Comment: glad to hear.  At stackoverflow it's important to mark the answer provided that resolved your question.  So if you could please accept the answer that worked for you, I'd appreciate it.  

Enjoy!